# Issue rendering image with react-email in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, resend.com

I'm creating an email using react-email in next js.  
I am having issue rendering my company logo which is located in my public directory 
notice the <img tag  
[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sokd5.png)  
My public directory and email directory are the ones of interest
the code snippet below is in the NewLead.tsx file

```
import {
  Body,
  Container,
  Column,
  Head,
  Html,
  Img,
  Link,
  Preview,
  Row,
  Section,
  Text,
} from "@react-email/components";

import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
  name: string;
  business_name: string;
  email_address: string;
  phone_number: string;
  requested_dollar_amount: string;
  gross_monthly_revenue: string;
}

function formatNumberWithCommas(numberStr: string): string {
  // First, validate if the input is a valid number
  if (!/^\d+$/.test(numberStr)) {
    return "Invalid input";
  }

  // Reverse the string to insert commas every three digits
  const reversedStr = numberStr.split("").reverse().join("");

  let formattedStr = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < reversedStr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
      formattedStr += ",";
    }
    formattedStr += reversedStr[i];
  }

  // Reverse the string back to its original order and add a dollar sign
  return "$" + formattedStr.split("").reverse().join("");
}

interface Props {
  name: string;
  business_name: string;
  email_address: string;
  phone_number: string;
  requested_dollar_amount: string;
  gross_monthly_revenue: string;
}

export const NewLeadEmail = ({
  name,
  business_name,
  email_address,
  phone_number,
  requested_dollar_amount,
  gross_monthly_revenue,
}: Props) => (
  <Html>
    <Head />
    <Preview>AI Capital New Lead</Preview>

    <Body style={main}>
      <Container style={container}>
        <Section>
          <Column>
            <Img
              src={"/images/ai-capital.png"}
              width="150"
              height="100"
              alt="AI Capital Logo"
            />
          </Column>

          <Column align="right" style={tableCell}>
            <Text style={heading}>New Lead</Text>
          </Column>
        </Section>

        <Section style={informationTable}>
          <Row style={informationTableRow}>
            <Column colSpan={2}>
              <Row>
                <Column style={informationTableColumn}>
                  <Text style={informationTableLabel}>NAME</Text>
                  {name}
                </Column>
                <Column style={informationTableColumn}>
                  <Text style={informationTableLabel}>BUSINESS NAME</Text>
                  {business_name}
                </Column>
              </Row>

              <Row>
                <Column style={informationTableColumn}>
                  <Text style={informationTableLabel}>EMAIL</Text>
                  <Link
                    style={{
                      ...informationTableValue,
                      color: "#15c",
                      textDecoration: "underline",
                    }}
                  >
                    {email_address}
                  </Link>
                </Column>
                <Column style={informationTableColumn}>
                  <Text style={informationTableLabel}>PHONE NUMBER</Text>
                  <Link
                    style={{
                      ...informationTableValue,
                      color: "#15c",
                      textDecoration: "underline",
                    }}
                  >
                    {phone_number}
                  </Link>
                </Column>
              </Row>
            </Column>
            <Column style={informationTableColumn} colSpan={2}>
              <Row>
                <Column style={informationTableColumn}>
                  <Text style={informationTableLabel}>
                    REQUESTED DOLLAR AMOUNT
                  </Text>
                  {formatNumberWithCommas(requested_dollar_amount)}
                </Column>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Column style={informationTableColumn}>
                  <Text style={informationTableLabel}>
                    GROSS MONTHLY REVENUE
                  </Text>
                  {formatNumberWithCommas(gross_monthly_revenue)}{" "}
                </Column>
              </Row>
            </Column>
          </Row>
        </Section>
      </Container>
    </Body>
  </Html>
);

export default NewLeadEmail;
```

Tried a few different variations of importing strategies and moving around the img file, even when i put it in the same directory as NewLead.tsx it won't seem to render it